# Catching individual errors when using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, fetch

I'm trying to make multiple fetch calls at once, so far I've used [this](https://gomakethings.com/waiting-for-multiple-all-api-responses-to-complete-with-the-vanilla-js-promise.all-method/) page to reach a point where I can make multiple calls correctly. However the problem now is if one of those calls returns an error. What I'd like, is that if one URL is good and one is bad, the good URL still returns the JSON object, but the bad URL returns the error. But the catch statement notices one error and stops both calls.

My current code:

```
let resList = await Promise.all([
    fetch(goodURL),
    fetch(badURL)
]).then(responses => {
    return Promise.all(responses.map(response => {
        return response.json();
    }))
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});

console.log(resList);
```

Currently, logging `resList` returns `undefined` when I want it to return the JSON object from the good URL

Comment: Can you use [`.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) where your code is running ([browser](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_promise_allsettled), [Node](https://node.green/#ES2020-features--Promise-allSettled))?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's running in Node. I'll give that a try, cheers

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've given ```.allSettled``` a try, but for some reason I now get a ```response.json``` is not a function error. Not sure why changing the promise would have an effect on that?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, `.allSettled()` is probably your best bet.

You can also basically make your own version with something like this:

```
const results = await Promise.all(
  [a, b, c].map(p => 
    p.catch(err => { 
      /* do something with it if you want */ 
    }
  )
);
```

Basically, instead of having one catch on `Promise.all()`, you attach a catch to each `Promise` BEFORE giving it to `Promise.all()`. If one of them throws an error, it'll trigger its individual catch, which you can do whatever with. As long as you don't return something else, you'll end up with it returning `undefined`, which you can filter out.

For example, if `a` and `c` worked and `b` errored, your `results` would look like this:

```
['a', undefined, 'b']
```

And it'd be in the same order as you fed the promises in, so you could tell which was the failure.

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('a'), 100));
const b = new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject('b'), 200));
const c = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('c'), 50));

(async () => {
  const results = await Promise.all(
    [a, b, c].map(p => 
      p.catch(err => console.error('err', err))
    )
  );

  console.log(results);
})();
```